# Appending "Chapter #:" to numbered chapters but not unnumbered ones in a bibliography by section

Tags: biblatex, sectioning, numbering

I use the following code to general a bibliography-by-section in a 'book' document,
but this appends "Chapter #:" to all chapters, including unnumbered ones. How can I modify the code to only append it to numbered chapters?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
        natbib=true,
        style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{nameref} % For ref. by segment

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\defbibheading{bibintoc}{%
    \section*{Chapter \ref{refsegment:\therefsection\therefsegment}: 
    \nameref{refsegment:\therefsection\therefsegment}}
}

\begin{document}

    \chapter{Numbered chapter}
    \setcounter{chapter}{1}
    \begin{refsegment}
        \lipsum[1]
        \cite{glashow,weinberg}
    \end{refsegment}

    \chapter*{Unnumbered}
    \begin{refsegment}
        \lipsum[2]
        \cite{reese}
    \end{refsegment}

    \printbibheading
    \bibbysegment[heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

Comment: The most easy and obvious workaround would be to omit the string chapter including the number from the definition ;-).

Comment: Thanks, but I've already thought of that ;) I'd rather include the string, if possible without hacking the code to absurd lengths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you load the `hyperref` package, then information about whether the label is for a numbered or unnumbered chapter is written to in the `.aux` file.  You can then access this via the fourth element of the result of `\real@setref` and provide appropriate text.

For numbered chapters this fourth element is `chapter.7` for Chapter 7, for unnumbered chapters it is of the form `chapter*.1`.  You can use the `xstring` package to check for the existence of the substring `*.`

Here is a macro `\mychref` that prints the type of heading text you wish for depending whether the chapter is numbered or not.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\mychref}[1]{\IfSubStr{%
    \expandafter\real@setref\csname r@#1\endcsname\@fourthoffive{#1}%
  }{*.}{}{Chapter \ref{#1}: }\nameref{#1}}
\makeatother
```

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
        natbib=true,
        style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xstring,nameref,hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\mychref}[1]{\IfSubStr{%
    \expandafter\real@setref\csname r@#1\endcsname\@fourthoffive{#1}%
  }{*.}{}{Chapter \ref{#1}: }\nameref{#1}}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\defbibheading{bibintoc}{%
  \section*{\mychref{refsegment:\therefsection\therefsegment}}
}

\begin{document}

    \chapter{Numbered chapter}
    \setcounter{chapter}{1}
    \begin{refsegment}
        \lipsum[1]
        \cite{glashow,weinberg}
    \end{refsegment}

    \chapter*{Unnumbered}
    \begin{refsegment}
        \lipsum[2]
        \cite{reese}
    \end{refsegment}

    \printbibheading
    \bibbysegment[heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```